# TGA reading header with QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt, qdatastream, tga

I am trying to read a TGA file header with Qt QDataStream. I have the following structure from the specs with fixed types:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
/* TGA header */
struct tga_header_t
{
    quint8   id_lenght;            /* size of image id */
    quint8   colormap_type;        /* 1 is has a colormap */
    quint8   image_type;           /* compression type */

    /* Color Map Specification */
    quint16  cm_origin;            /* colormap origin */
    quint16  cm_length;            /* colormap length */
    quint8   cm_size;              /* colormap size */

    /* Image Specification */
    quint16  x_origin;           /* bottom left x coord origin */
    quint16  y_origin;           /* bottom left y coord origin */
    quint16  width;              /* picture width (in pixels) */
    quint16  height;             /* picture height (in pixels) */
    quint8   pixel_depth;        /* bits per pixel: 8, 16, 24 or 32 */
    quint8   image_descriptor;   /* 24 bits = 0x00; 32 bits = 0x80 */
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

I open a file with QFile then construct a QDataStream with it as such:

```
QFile file(path);
tga_header_t header;

file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QDataStream stream(&file);
stream >> header.id_lenght >>
          header.colormap_type >>
          header.image_type >>
          header.cm_origin >>
          header.cm_length >>
          header.cm_size >>
          header.x_origin >>
          header.y_origin >>
          header.width >>
          header.height >>
          header.pixel_depth >>
          header.image_descriptor;
qDebug() << header.id_lenght << "id_lenght" <<
            header.colormap_type << "colormap_type" <<
            header.image_type << "image_type" <<
            header.cm_origin << "cm_origin" <<
            header.cm_length << "cm_length" <<
            header.cm_size << "cm_size" <<
            header.x_origin << "x_origin" <<
            header.y_origin << "y_origin" <<
            header.width << "width" <<
            header.height << "height" <<
            header.pixel_depth << "pixel_depth" <<
            header.image_descriptor << "image_descriptor" <<
            "SIZE:" << sizeof(header);
```

The problem is with width and height I get :

```
0 id_lenght 0 colormap_type 2 image_type 0 cm_origin 0 cm_length 0 cm_size 0 x_origin 0 y_origin 22021 width 3 height 24 pixel_depth 0 image_descriptor SIZE: 18
```

And I should get 1366 and 768. If I hexdump the file I get :

```
0000000 0000 0002 0000 0000 0000 0000 0556 0300
0000010 0018 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Which is weird because it has an extra byte at the start and another missing somewhere between `0x0002` and `0x0556`.

**Update:**
Using fstream works, so correct me if I am wrong but I think the `<<` operator does not work as I expect it to (read only the size necessary to fill the struct variable).

```
    stream.read((char*)&header.id_lenght, sizeof(header.id_lenght));
    stream.read((char*)&header.colormap_type, sizeof(header.colormap_type));
    stream.read((char*)&header.image_type, sizeof(header.image_type));
    stream.read((char*)&header.cm_origin, sizeof(header.cm_origin));
    stream.read((char*)&header.cm_length, sizeof(header.cm_length));
    stream.read((char*)&header.cm_size, sizeof(header.cm_size));
    stream.read((char*)&header.x_origin, sizeof(header.x_origin));
    stream.read((char*)&header.y_origin, sizeof(header.y_origin));
    stream.read((char*)&header.width, sizeof(header.width));
    stream.read((char*)&header.height, sizeof(header.height));
    stream.read((char*)&header.pixel_depth, sizeof(header.pixel_depth));
    stream.read((char*)&header.image_descriptor, sizeof(header.image_descriptor));
```

Using QDataStream::readRawData also works:

```
stream.readRawData((char*)&header.id_lenght, sizeof(header.id_lenght));
    stream.readRawData((char*)&header.colormap_type, sizeof(header.colormap_type));
    stream.readRawData((char*)&header.image_type, sizeof(header.image_type));
    stream.readRawData((char*)&header.cm_origin, sizeof(header.cm_origin));
    stream.readRawData((char*)&header.cm_length, sizeof(header.cm_length));
    stream.readRawData((char*)&header.cm_size, sizeof(header.cm_size));
    stream.readRawData((char*)&header.x_origin, sizeof(header.x_origin));
    stream.readRawData((char*)&header.y_origin, sizeof(header.y_origin));
    stream.readRawData((char*)&header.width, sizeof(header.width));
    stream.readRawData((char*)&header.height, sizeof(header.height));
    stream.readRawData((char*)&header.pixel_depth, sizeof(header.pixel_depth));
    stream.readRawData((char*)&header.image_descriptor, sizeof(header.image_descriptor));
```

Comment: `stream >> header.id_lenght; ...` is this a typo? I believe it should be `stream >> header.id_lenght >> ...`.

Comment: Yes this was a typo(corrected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is OK. Your PC interprets 16-bit words as little-endian. In the file they are stored as big endians.

For all 16-bit types you should swap low/high bytes. You also could use the helper functions from Qt: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtendian.html